# Problemas busca php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

Estou fazendo um campo para busca porém me retorna alguns erros.
Meu código:

```
class Prog{
  private $DtBase;

   public function setdata($DtBase){
    $this->data = $DtBase;
   }
   public function getdata(){
    return convertarData($this->data);
   }  

   public function convertarData($data)
   {

    $exp = explode("/",$data);
    return $exp[2].'-'.$exp[1].'-'.$exp[0].'-';
   }
}
```

**progDAO**

```
class ProgDAO{

private $conn;

public function __construct($connection){
    $this->conn = $connection;
}

public function Busca($obj){
        $results = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DtBase = "'.$obj->getdata().'" ');
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setcarreta($row->CdCarreta);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}
```

**progControle**

```
class Comando{

private $conn;

   public function __construct($connec) {
    $this->conn = $connec;
   }

   public function Busca(Comando $obj){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> Busca($obj);
   }
}
```

**progPrecontrole**

```
include_once ('../connection_open.php');

include_once ('../model/prog.php');
include_once ('progControle.php');
include_once ('../DAO/progDAO.php');

$dataPost = $_POST['data'];

$objProg = new Prog();
$objProg->setdata($dataPost);

$objComando = new Comando();
$objComando->Busca($objProg);


header ("location: ../view/busca.php");

include_once ('../connection_close.php');
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Busca</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Campo para busca</h1>
    <form action="../controller/progPrecontrole.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid();">
        Data: <input type="date" id="data" name="data">
        <input type="submit" class="success round button" value="Buscar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Problemas:

> **Warning**: Missing argument 1 for Comando::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progPrecontrole.php on line 16 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progControle.php on line 7
>
> **Notice**: Undefined variable: connec in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progControle.php on line 8
>
> **Catchable fatal error**: Argument 1 passed to Comando::Busca() must be an instance of Comando, instance of Prog given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progPrecontrole.php on line 17 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progControle.php on line 11

Comment: O último erro vc inverteu as variáveis deve passar `$objComando` em `Busca()` e não `$objProg`. Como o códigode progControle não está ai não tem como dizer exatamente como resolver mas a mensagem de erro já ajuda bastante ;)

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta ele está ai só não sinalizei. Já editei sinalizando, não sei se ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing argument 1 for Comando::__construct()

Faltou passar o argumento(variável ou valor) no construtor de `Comando`, provavelmente aqui:

```
$objComando = new Comando(); //<---- cadê o argumento que é a conexão com o banco?
$objComando->Busca($objProg);
```

> Argument 1 passed to Comando::Busca() must be an instance of Comando, instance of Prog given

Foi passado o tipo erradado para `Busca()` deve ser um `Comando` e não um `Prog` segundo a mensagem de erro porém acho que a sua intenção é passar `Prog` mesmo uma vez que esse objeto tem o método `setData()` para isso basta corrigir o tipo na assinatura do método.

Mude:

```
class Comando{
   //código omitido
   public function Busca(Comando $obj){
```

Para:

```
class Comando{
   //código omitido
   public function Busca(Prog $obj){
```

---

### Dicas não relacionadas ao problema principal

- Utilize prepared statements da forma correta.

Mude:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DtBase = "'.$obj->getdata().'" ');
```

Para:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DtBase = ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $obj->getdata());
```

- Converta a data de forma simplificada e correta(tem um `-` a mais nesse método)

Mude:

```
public function convertarData($data){
   $exp = explode("/",$data);
   return $exp[2].'-'.$exp[1].'-'.$exp[0].'-';
}
```

Para:

```
 public function convertarData($data){
    $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
    return $data->format('Y-m-d');
 }
```

Comment: Perfeito, porém relatou mais um erro`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Comando::Busca() must be an instance of Prog, instance of Comando given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progPrecontrole.php on line 15 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\controller\progControle.php on line 11`

Comment: @Kevin.F vc trocou o tipo na declaração da função?

Comment: Sim coloquei `Prog` envés de `Comando` como dito acima, agora foi. Só deu mais um erro na `function` de converter a data `Fatal error: Call to undefined function convertarData() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teste2\model\Prog.php on line 115`

Comment: @Kevin.F no `busca()` do DAO, da um `print_r($obj)` veja o que aparece

Comment: Aparece algo como:`Prog Object ( [id:Prog:private] => [NrPlaca:Prog:private] => [data] => )`

Comment: @Kevin.F veio em branco faz o seguinte em `Prog` depois de `private $DtBase;` adicione, `private $data;`

Comment: Certo, agora ele voltou assim `[data:Prog:private]` porém o erro persiste.

Comment: @Kevin.F o `setdata()` parece não estar funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Se eu tiro o `convertarData` depois do `return` funciona, não me retorna erro.

Comment: @Kevin.F mostra como vc está chamando

Comment: Está tudo ai no `class Prog` só alterei a function como você postou acima na resposta.

Comment: Acho que eu não estou chamando em nem um lugar por isso o erro.

Comment: @Kevin.F o problema para ser em outro lugar, se vc seguir o fluxo vai ver q `$obj` tem o `getdata()` e não poderia der esse erro de undefined method.

Comment: pois é, bem estranho não detectei o que pode ser.