# Erro "Catchable fatal error" PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Possuo um campo busca em que posto uma data dinâmica, postando essa data me retorna os registros do banco abaixo, porém travei neste erro que acontece no `foreach`. Segue código:

**DAO:**

```
public function ListaPorTipoB($obj){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DsTpVeiculo = \'Bitruck\' AND DtBase = ?');
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $obj->getdata());
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Comando{

  private $conn;

  public function __construct($connec) {
    $this->conn = $connec;
  }

  public function ListaPorTipoB(Prog $obj){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> ListaPorTipoB($obj);
  }
}
```

**Precontrol:**

```
include_once ('../connection_open.php');

include_once ('../model/prog.php');
include_once ('progControle.php');
include_once ('../DAO/progDAO.php');


$dataPost = $_POST['dataa'];

$objProg = new Prog();
$objProg->setdata($dataPost);

$controller = new Comando($conn);
$controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg);


header ("location: ../view/programacao.php");

include_once ('../connection_close.php');
```

**Campo busca e abaixo retorna os registros do banco:**

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/buscaPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <input type="date" id="dataa" name="dataa" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="large-9 columns">
                <input type="submit" class="tiny round button" value="Filtrar"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB() as $objProg) { ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                 </table>
               </div>
         </div>
  </form>
```

> **Catchable fatal error**: Argument 1 passed to Comando::ListaPorTipoB() must be an instance of Prog, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\view\programacao.php on line 76 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\controller\progControle.php on line 11

Não estou conseguindo resolver este erro, alguma dica ?

Comment: É o mesmo erro da [pergunta passada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119391/91), vc precisa passar um objeto `Prog` nessa linha `foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB() as $objProg`

Comment: É obrigatório passar a data para `ListaPorTipoB()` ?

Comment: Não, se tiver outro jeito de fazer, com o mesmo fim e for mais viável . E não consegui passar o objeto prog nessa linha acima.

Comment: Se a data não interessa, é so cortar ela fora 1) do SQL. 2) Remover o bind 3) Remover do método `ListaPorTipoB($obj){` no DAO. 4) Remover do méotodo `ListaPorTipoB(Prog $obj){` em Comando.

Comment: Mas ela interessa sim. Preciso dela. Como passo o objeto para a linha que comentou acima ? Pois tentei passar e não funcionou, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Antes do foreach faça `$objProg = new Prog();$objProg->setdata('2016-03-24');`. depois:  `foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg) as $objProg`

Comment: Só que esta data é dinâmica conforme posto no campo busca encima do `foreach` não posso setar ela manual ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o erro modificando alguns códigos abaixo:

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/buscaPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <input type="date" id="data" name="data" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="large-9 columns">
                <input type="submit" class="tiny round button" value="Filtrar"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['data'])){

                        $dataPost = $_GET['data'];

                        $objProg = new Prog();
                        $objProg->setdata($dataPost);

                    }else{

                        $dataPost = date('Y-m-d');

                        $objProg = new Prog();
                        $objProg->setdata($dataPost);


                    }


                     foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg) as $objProg) { ?>
```

Precontrol:

```
$dataPost = $_POST['data'];

$objProg = new Prog();
$objProg->setdata($dataPost);

$controller = new Comando($conn);
$controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg);


header ("location: ../view/programacao.php?data=".$dataPost."");
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que isso resolva, pois a questão basicamente é que você está chamando um método sem passar valor, na classe é obrigatório passar um valor, para resolver você pode criar um segundo método que faça o mesmo, sem ter passar um objeto, para isso que existem métodos do tipo `Set` e `Get`, entretanto, para o exemplo que você está fazendo teria que ser algo similar a isso:

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/buscaPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <input type="date" id="dataa" name="dataa" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="large-9 columns">
                <input type="submit" class="tiny round button" value="Filtrar"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                         if(!$_POST) {
                           $content = null;
                           } else {
                             $obj = new Prog();
                             $type = $obj->setdata($_POST['dataa']);
                             if ($controller instanceof Comando)):
                                $content = $controller->ListaPorTipoB($type);
                             }
                        if (!empty($content)):
                           foreach ($content as $objProg): ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                 <?php else:>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="10">Sem registros.</td>
                        </tr>
                 <?php endif; ?>
               <?php else:>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="10">Sem registros.</td>
                        </tr>
             <?php endif; ?>
                 </table>
               </div>
         </div>
  </form>
```

veja se ao invés de fazer tudo isso que eu fiz acima, não seria melhor fazer isso:

```
include_once ('../connection_open.php');

include_once ('../model/prog.php');
include_once ('progControle.php');
include_once ('../DAO/progDAO.php');


$dataPost = $_POST['dataa'];

$objProg = new Prog();
$objProg->setdata($dataPost);

$controller = new Comando($conn);
//atribuindo a saída para uma variável
$data = $controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg);

include_once ('../connection_close.php');
```

Na view:

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/buscaPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <input type="date" id="dataa" name="dataa" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="large-9 columns">
                <input type="submit" class="tiny round button" value="Filtrar"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $objProg) { ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                 </table>
               </div>
         </div>
  </form>
```

Só uma observação, sobre sua classe:
Tome cuidado com métodos recursivos, pois isso pode afetar o desempenho se for mal escrito.

Comment: Me retornou duas mensagens de erro no `foreach` - Notice: Undefined variable: data in line 78 - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 78

Comment: Esse erro, indica que a variável `$data` não está  passando nada para o laço foreach... você já deu um `var_dump($controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg)); die(); ` para ver se existe alguma saída nisso? Lembrando que você está usando método recursivo... veja se isso está correto.

Comment: Aonde eu executo esse `var_dump($controller->ListaPorTipoB($objProg)); die(); ? `